# How can I disable server certificate validation in Serilog using appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, serilog, appsettings

When using the email sink in serilog I get the error

Failed to send email: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Through code, I can supply on the EmailConnectionInfo:

`ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true`

But I am using appsettings.json to load the Serilog configuration.

Is it possible to supply it through appsettings.json somehow?

I tried (stripped sensitive fields in the below example) without luck, same error:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Email" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Email",
        "Args": {
          "connectionInfo": {
            "FromEmail": "",
            "ToEmail": "",
            "MailServer": "",
            "EmailSubject": "",
            "serverCertificateValidationCallback": "(s, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible to configure the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` via configuration. You'll have to configure it via code.

You can open an issue in the [`Serilog.Settings.Configuration` repository](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) to track a feature request for configuring callbacks via configuration files and/or open an issue in the [`Serilog.Sinks.Email` repository](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email/issues) to see if a workaround can be implemented in the future.

Comment: Thanks you. Do you happen to know what should be done to accept the self signed certificate in the context of Serilog?

Comment: @Coder80 `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is the way to go. You just need to check for policy errors, so you don't accept invalid certificates. Example: https://gist.github.com/caioproiete/86015cf64043fd0ee43b83dc38353c2d